# "Searching" a string on a MongoDB DB with MongoMapper

Tags: sql, search, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I'm making a webapp where I'm using MongoMapper and Sinatra. I wonder how could I implement a search feature against a DB's collection. I though something like SQL's:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE match(title) against ("String to search");
```

How could I achieve this with MongoMapper? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is from my project and does work:

```
Post.where(:title => Regexp.new(/^string/i))   # Limit output with: .limit(10)
```

Maybe it's the Regexp?

Comment: glad I could help. It's the little things that the docs are missing :)

Answer (score 0):

You query for documents that match a case sensitive rooted regular expression:

```
Post.where(:title => /^stringtosearch/).first
```

MongoDB does not support full text search so this is the best you can do at the moment.

Comment: I'm getting a `#<Plucky::Query:0x007fc33c4d4c50>`. From what I had seen (pretty much a beginner) I've never had success with those. Could you give me some directions?. Also testing it with `empty?` returns `true`

Comment: Post.where(:title => "stringtosearch") will also work and will match only exact this String.

Comment: @three I don't need that, I need to match all the results wich contains that string

Comment: @TylerBrock you have to tell plucky that you're using a regexp.